# jQuery plugin - tablesorter error on first function call

Tags: jquery

I'm using the jQuery tablesorter plugin and initialising it in my code as per the documentation. My code is set up that when a td in table-two is clicked, it makes some changes to a corresponding td in table-one and then reorders the table. The code gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

But when I click the td again, it works and continues to work. So it's just the first time the function is called.

In brief, my code is set up as follows:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
     $("#table-one").tablesorter();
});
```

and then

```
$(document).on('click','td.team',function() {

     // make some changes to table-one here, renumber the rows etc

     $("#table-one").trigger("update");
     $("#table-one").tablesorter( {sortList: [[4,1] , [3,1]]} )
});
```

So its only the first time I click on a td in table-two that fires the error. Then if I click the td in table-two again and again and again it continues to work as expected. Bizarre, any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle...

Comment: weird. it works fine in a fiddle with some stripped back code...http://jsfiddle.net/Fj76u/

Comment: i think its something to do with the fact that im loading my table content from an ajax request. it works ok when the data is hardcoded in the fiddle, but cant get it working when its loaded via ajax. something to do with it not being in the dom or something? baffled.

Comment: Well, you have to init the tablesort plugin within the success method inside $.ajax() to ensure the markup allready is present / added to DOM.

Comment: i init the tablesorter in the document.on('ready')... if I put that in the .done(function())... of the getJSON request it doesnt make any difference. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Document Ready is sync but Ajax() always is async... your markup is not present when you init the plugin. Use the done() method, right!

Comment: hmm. still the same error putting the init in the .done() function. Weird one this.

Comment: You have to init the plugin once the table's markup was added. Update your jsfiddle with the Ajax call - please provide the tablesort plugin as external resource (inside the left sidebar)

Comment: thanks redaxmedia, always struggle putting ajax calls into jsfiddle but will see what i can do. also, the tablesorter is downloaded code so has no url to include and cant work out how to give jsfiddle permission to access my server side scripts. anyway, a lot of learning for me there, but will try to improve the fiddle. I get what you mean about init'ing after the content has loaded, although I think I am doing that. Cheers for your help thus far.